# datatable datetime column dont have milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, milliseconds

I have a date time value as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff in my database column.

But when I get that into a .net datatable, and get it as DateTime...I am not getting the milliseconds part.

Is there any type of casting that I am missing ?

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dtRow[colIndex])
```

This is my code, where dtRow is a particular column in my data table.

Edit:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", Convert.ToDateTime(dtRow[colIndex]))
```

"2014-07-28 15:18:43.000"

where actual value is "2014-07-28 15:18:43.866".

Thanks!

Comment: it is not a string - it is date time datatype.

Comment: How are you accessing the result set? Why do you try to parse it as a string? If you use ADO.NET and `SqlDataReader` just call its `GetDateTime` method. No need to convert anything.

Comment: this is data table, not data reader - I am dealing with huge amount of data.

Comment: Just drop the `Convert.ToDateTime` call. If the value is already a `DateTime` you don't need to convert anything.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this the problem which lead me here.  The default "ToString" uses the CurrentCulture which (most likely) uses a Format that leaves off the milliseconds.  Therefore Parsing etc doesn't work because that converts it to a String (which is the problem!) and back again, thus dropping the ms.

However, the "object" is a DateTime.  This means you can simply cast the item to a DateTime variable and use it.  In my case I had a datetime from a SQL statement that I needed to store as a String - and noticed they all had .000 for milliseconds when Parsed.

My particular requirement was that I didn't know the Type of the column - hence the default ToString at the end.

```
private static string ConvertFieldToString(DataRow row, string fieldName)
{
  if (row.IsNull(fieldName))
     return null;

  if (row[fieldName].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
  {
     DateTime dt = (DateTime)row[fieldName];
     return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt");
  }
  return row.ToString();
}
```

The output will look like:  2018-04-18 03:30:43.233 PM

Read more on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtRow[colIndex]);
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", dt)
```

Comment: Please see my edit...ur code will print milli seconds if the value is present...but data table itself somehow cut that value.

Comment: You need to do the `String.Format` while fetching the data from the SQL then the data would be present in the `datatable` as well. Please show the code where you are fetching the values from `SQL` to `DataTable`

Comment: I am querying as select * from table1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string dateString = dtRow[colIndex];
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            r[0] = i;
            r[1] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-i);
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        foreach (var r in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", r[0], r[1]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If the value added into `DataTable` was `DateTime` you don't need to convert anything, it's already `DateTime`, formatting functions will figure everything out just fine. If you need to access individual properties programmatically, just cast it:

```
DateTime timestamp = (DateTime)r[1];
```